# Sum with a fraction with an index returns 1

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, sum, fractions

I want to sum of all the fractions from 1 to 1/100, but when I compile the following code i get "1".

```
#include <stdio.h> 

main(){ 
    int i,sum; 
    sum=0;
    for (i=1;i<=100;i++){ 
        sum=sum+(1/i);
    }
printf("%d",sum);
}
```

Shouldn't the for loop return

- i=1 --> sum=0+(1/1)
- i=2 --> sum=1+(1/2)
- i=3 --> sum= 3/2 + (1/3)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are doing integer divisions. This means `1/i == 0` for any `i != 1` and `1 + 0 + 0 + 0 ... == 1`

Comment: You have integer sum too, so that will also dump any fractional part.

Comment: You are missing the concept of _integer division_.  The idea that an _int_ divided by an _int_ will produce an _int_ as output, and therefore cannot represent a fraction like 1/3 -- and all that entails.  And you haven't learned the typical workaround which is to cast one (or more) of the operands to be a floating point type, which will result in a floating point division and a floating point result. I acknowledge that your code seems logical, but unfortunately it just doesn't do what you intended given the behaviour of C with respect to the division operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using integers, `1/i` always rounds to `0`, so your sum never changes.
Replace `int` with `float` or `double`.